# Doubts about Array.prototype.some ()

Tags: javascript, json

This piece of code comes from a freeCodeCamp challenge. And it works. But I need some clarification. In the exercise, it is about reading a json array to extract the value of the given **firstName** property when calling the **lookUp function**. Also, check such property exists before reading its value.

When **contacts.some** declares the callback **function (arg) {...}**, it seems that 'arg' already knows the 'firstName' and 'prop' parameters passed when calling the lookUp function.

```js
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];

function lookUp(firstName, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line
  var answer = "No such contact";
  contacts.some(function(arg) {
    if (arg.firstName === firstName && arg.hasOwnProperty(prop) === true) {
      answer = arg[prop];
    } else if (arg.hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) {
      answer = "No such property";
    }
  });
  return answer;
  // Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUp("Kristian", "lastName");
```

I do not understand where the magic is. Why does 'arg' contain the value of both parameters? Could anyone explain how this happens?

Thanks in advance.
Carlos.

Comment: *"...it is about reading a json array"* No, it's about reading an array. No JSON involved. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: This is all explained in the documentation for [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Note that the code you've found there is quite poor, see my comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41880800/157247) for a concise version of why (and those are just the things I noted in a quick scan through).

Comment: @TedHopp: True, though it probably doesn't help that the code is misusing `some` and relying on closures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function as written contains logic errors which will prevent it from doing what it is designed to do. However, I am going to address specifically your question about how the callback can see the `lookUp` function's parameters and properties in array items.

In JavaScript, functions defined within a given scope can see the variables from the scope they're in. So, for instance:

```
var variable = 5;

function incrementVariable()
{
  variable++;
}
```

In this sample, `incrementVariable` can see the variable `variable` even though it is defined outside of the function. In this sample, `variable` is global, but this could be done inside of another function:

```
function doSomething()
{
  var variable = 5;

  function incrementVariable()
  {
    variable++;
  }

  ...
  incrementVariable();
  ...
}
```

Parameters to a function are just another type of variable, so for instance:

```
function doSomething(variable)
{
  function incrementVariable()
  {
    variable++;
  }

  ...
  incrementVariable();
  ...
}

doSomething(5);
```

In the `lookUp` function you posted, the argument to `contacts.some(..)` is a `function` defined within the `lookUp` function, so it can "see" everything that the `lookUp` function itself can see, including its parameters.

The technical term for this type of shared scope is a "closure".

The `arg` argument to the callback function is defined by what the `some()` function itself is doing. The callback gets called once for each of the elements in the `contacts` array. So, for instance, the first call back has this in `arg`:

```
{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
}
```

Thus, the callback can see both `firstName`, the argument to lookUp, and `arg.firstName`, which in this case is the string `"Akira"`. Similarly, if `prop` is, say, `"number"`, then `arg[prop]` refers to the `"number"` property in that object, which in this case will be `"0543236543"`.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that the code is misusing `some`, has a completely pointless `=== true` comparison, calls `hasOwnProperty` repeatedly rather than just once, and gives the wrong result if there's a matching contact at, say, index 1 but an object later at, say, index 3 which doesn't have the `firstName` property.

Comment: These things are all true, but are separate issues from the question of how the callback can see the arguments to `lookUp` and properties of the objects in the array. :-)

Comment: If that's the question (I'm still not entirely sure what the question actually is), but frankly a couple of those really should be noted in *any* answer to this question.